# Docker: how to update changes in php.ini inside of container

Tags: php, date, datetime, docker

I have a docker container which has `php5.6` inside. When I test some things I get this error : `strtotime(): It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone settings. You are *required* to use the date.timezone setting or the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the timezone identifier. We selected the timezone 'UTC' for now, but please set date.timezone to select your timezone.` This can be changed with appending `date.timezone = America/New_York` to my `php.ini` file. That's exactly what I am doing. But it is not working, it seems, that I should restart some service to really "update" my `php.ini` file. So, what should I do to update my php.ini file changes ?

Answer (score 0):

> So, what should I do to update my php.ini file changes ?

change your source `php.ini` file and re-build your image

if you change the file in teh container itself, the moment you stop the container and restart it, the change will be gone.

so, you need to update your php.ini file from your source and then rebuild the image to include this change